# Which formal language class are XML and JSON with unique keys (they are not context-free)

Tags: xml, json, computer-science, language-theory, formal-languages

> **Please don't answer here but at cstheory.stackexchange, where [I copied this question to](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4668/which-formal-language-class-are-xml-and-json-with-unique-keys)!**

JSON and XML are both frequently called to be context-free languages - they are both specified mainly by a formal grammar in EBNF. However this is only true for JSON as defined in [RFC 4329, section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.2) which does not require uniqueness of object keys (many may not know but {"a":1,"a":2} is valid JSON!). But if you require unique keys in JSON or [unique attribute names in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#uniqattspec) this cannot be expressed by a context-free grammars. But which is the language class of JSON with unique keys and for well-formed XML (which implies unique attribute names?).

One of the best paper I found on this subject (Murato et al, 2001: [Taxonomy of XML Schema Languages using Formal Language Theory](http://www.cobase.cs.ucla.edu/tech-docs/dongwon/mura0619.pdf)) explicitly excludes integrity constraints such as keys/keyrefs and uniqueness to be checked on an additional layer. Beside this the subset of XML defined by an XML Schema or by a DTD is context-free. But not the full set of all well-formed XML documents.

I think a nested stack automaton (=indexed language) should be able to parse JSON with unique key constraint. For XML can simlify the question to the language S of all comma-seperated lists of unique integers. Does anyone know more, preferably with citations?

**P.S:** A simple algorithm to decide the languages (beside the context-free part) is based on a good sorting algorithm. Therefore it should be decidable in "linearithmic time" with O(n log n) worst case. I have not found out yet, whether the complexity class is for instance *"mildly context-sensitive"*, or *"indexed"* but probably something between context-free and context-sensitive (?).

Comment: Let's close this question as off-topic and point to: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4668/which-formal-language-class-are-xml-and-json-with-unique-keys